# Element is visible in normal mode but not visible in headless mode when using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

This is the element:

```
<i class="material-symbols-outlined" translate="no" data-id="Icon" style="font-size: 24px; font-variation-settings: &quot;FILL&quot; 0, &quot;wght&quot; 400, &quot;GRAD&quot; 0, &quot;opsz&quot; 14;">account_circle</i>
```

This is how I locate it:

```
public static By accountButton = By.XPath("//i[contains(., 'account_circle')]");
```

And this is how I set up the headless mode. I use browser extension too.

```
 var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.AddArguments("--headless=new");
        option.AddExtension(MainPageElements.extensionPath);
        option.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
        option.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        option.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");

        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, option);
```

I tried locating in different way using CssSelector, but still no success.

edit: I also tried locating a completly different element and it still does not see it so the issue is not the element.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The error is - Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 120 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//i[contains(., 'account_circle')]"}

Comment: I also tried locating a completly different element and it still does not see it so the issue is not the element.

Comment: You should create screenshot in your TearDown to be sure page was loaded without any problems.

Maybe your extension has problems with headless and something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Headless mode using `Selenium` is highly **NOT recommended**. It will often cause latency, elements not to be found or not to be clicked well or focused. If you can - avoid using the headless mode.

If you must, give the `Selenium` plugin an "easy life". Be more direct on the type of elements you are looking for, and search for text. Try this:

```
public static By accountButton  = 
By.XPath("//i[contains(text(), 'account_circle')]");
```

Also, try to use the `WebDriverWait` element, set a timeout threshold and wait for specific conditions like element to be visible, clickable etc'.

Comment: I want to useless headless mode just because I am trying to bypass cloudflare bot protection and I read that this might be one way to do it. But you are saying that it is NOT recommended so I guess I will not be using it. The thing is that I still need to find a way to bypass the cloudflare. Any idea if headless mode could do the job at all?